# C# Mono Microsecond timer

Tags: c#, timer, mono, raspberry-pi, archlinux

I need a C# application running in mono on Arch Linux on a Raspberry Pi to send serial commands at regular intervals to connected hardware. I have estimated my maximum speed and accuracy needed to be 0,0001 seconds so this is just to high for a millisecond timer, I would therefore like to know if there is some Linux library that I can use to achieve microsecond timing and if so how to use it.

Comment: what serial bus are you talking about?

Comment: I am thinking about using SPI,i2c or UART, I have not decided yet but I think I will be using SPI